# Using Core Data in a shared Swift App Framework

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, watchkit

I have an App Framework that contains my Core Data objects which is shared between an iPhone App and a WatchKit App Extension using a shared App Group.

The Framework and its Core Data code all works perfectly from when called from the iPhone App, but when I fetch my objects through the WatchKit extension to populate the Watch, Core Data only returns a subset of my data.

I've managed to troubleshoot this to an unknown issue with records that have a one-to-many child relationship defined (Post [1...*] Replies).  The Framework when called from WatchKit code will return all the Posts until it encounters a Post with one or more Reply children.  It returns that Post (and any that Reply-less Posts that proceeded it), but not the Replies and no Posts after that.  The Framework when called from the iPhone code, works as it should and returns all Posts and their Replies.

I've been banging my head against the wall for days trying to track down the issue and can't get the Framework, when called from the WatchKit extension, to output any type of logging or breakpoints.

I've tried recreating the model with no change in behavior.  I've removed the Core Data class prefix (e.g. AppFramework.LocalPost) and instead used @objc so my Classes in the Framework are currently defined like so

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(LocalPost)
public class LocalPost: NSManagedObject {
    ...
}


import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(LocalPostReply)
public class LocalPostReply: NSManagedObject {
    ...
}
```

But nothing I've done has helped.  The code when called from the WatchKit extension simply doesn't like Replies.

Anyone experience similar issues of have tips on how to troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after several days or trial and error I finally found something that worked.  I had to set the relationship in both directions to optional even though a Reply would always have a Post parent.  Not sure why that fixed it, or why it only had an issue in the WatchKit Extension, but it all works now.